# Method Overriding in Exception handling

Tags: exception, try-catch-finally

In exception handling, it is known that, if the super class method does not declare an exception, subclass overridden method cannot declare the checked exception but it can declare unchecked exception. Why so? consider the following example :

```
import java.io.*;

class Parent {
    void msg() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

class TestExceptionChild extends Parent {
    void msg() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("TestExceptionChild");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent p = new TestExceptionChild();
        p.msg();
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

We get compilation error here. If I need to read a file in the overridden method "msg", then I have to mention "throws IOException" there. But java doesn't allow them. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are violating the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), i.e: you can't replace the instance of the superclass with one of the subclass because you are modifying the signature of the method `msg` in the father superclass.

In the more general class, the method `msg` doesn't throw any exception, and you want to modify the signature in the subclass, which is obviously unallowed, because it violates the contract of the `override` principal.

Answer (score 0):

You need remember one thing that if you are using throws keyword than any exception arises will be forwarded into the calling chain and in case of overriding at compilation time compiler checks weather the overridden method is there in parent or not and JVM execute the child class method.
So,basically from parent the child method is called and hence it should be capable of handling checked exception if child method throws any exception otherwise CE..
I Hope It Helps :)